# How to load page based on JQuery dropdownlist value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got a ASPX webpage that I'm building to generate reports based on filter criteria's. I've got a jqxwidget that I use to get my dropdown list, which gets it's values from a var I've created:

```
var sourceRptType = [
            { value: '0', label: 'Hours & Labour Cost By Employee' },
            { value: '1', label: 'Hours & Labour Cost By Project' },
            { value: '2', label: 'Premiums & Allowances By Employee' },
            { value: '3', label: 'Premiums & Allowances By Project' },
            { value: '4', label: 'Daily Labour Costs & Allowances By Employee' },
            { value: '5', label: 'Daily Labour Costs & Allowances - Raw Data' },
            { value: '6', label: 'Daily Labour Costs & Allowances By Employee w/ Premiums' },
            { value: '7', label: 'Daily Labour Costs & Allowances By Employee w/ Allowance Breakout' },
            { value: '8', label: 'Daily Labour Costs & Allowances w/ Premiums - Raw Data' },
        ];
```

I want my button to load a webpage based on the value selected above. How can I get my button to load the selected dropdownlist value?

Comment: How do you want the respective page to load? In a container on that page or refresh with corresponding URL to view that report?

Comment: I'd like it to load on that same page

Answer (score 0):

You did share the HTML output or mention the `select` element ID but I guess it to be `report_type` and let's say you have a table with ID `report_table` where the report data will be displayed.

```
$('select').first().on( 'change', function() {
    // get the report ID
    var reportID = $(this).val();

    // pass that to your API endpoint or any file to process your request
    // via AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someFile.asp',
        data: {
            report: reportID
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            // let's suppose your response is in JSON

            // target table
            var table = $('#reports_table');

            // insert the data
            response.each(function( index, row ){
                table.append('<tr><td>' + row.title + '</td></tr>');
                // depends on your data but should not be hard to guess
            })
        }
    })
} );
```

Note: The code above is not tested and might have some errors and may vary depending on your data and environment.

Let me know if it helps and if you need further assistance.